Multiple CSV File into One CSV file adding the Field Column wise with Bash Script
I have multiple CSV files where data is like below
file1.csv->
1107,1088,1087,1171
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
221479,135000,180000,22500
file2.csv->
1107,1088,1087,1171
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
219015,135000,180000,22500
file3.csv->
1107,1088,1087,1171
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
221962,135000,180000,22500
file4.csv->
1107,1088,1087,1171
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
360000,135000,180000,22500
216591,135000,180000,22500
Output file should be like summation of each column header wise and write it in a output csv file.
output.csv->
1107,1088,1087
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
0,0,0
1440000,540000,720000
1440000,540000,720000
1440000,540000,720000
1440000,540000,720000
1440000,540000,720000
1440000,540000,720000
879047,540000,720000
I want to do it with below command in a bash script but getting output with only header and blanklike below.
1107,1088,1087
Command:
FILE_PATTERN="/gfs-backup/robi_icms/sadman_scripts/UCG_Report/projection/${dt}*.csv"

head -n 1 "$(ls $FILE_PATTERN | head -n 1)" > "$output_file"

declare -a column_sums
# Sum each row across all CSV files
for file in $FILE_PATTERN; do
    echo "Processing $file"
    tail -n +2 "$file" | while IFS=',' read -r -a row_values; do
        for i in "${!row_values[@]}"; do
            column_sums[$i]=$(( ${column_sums[$i]:-0} + ${row_values[$i]} ))
        done
    done
done

# Write the summed values to the output file
{
    echo "${column_sums[*]}" | tr ' ' ','
} >> "$output_file"

echo "Summed values have been written to $output_file."


No Linux-specific API used here, just Bash, so I removed the tag.

There you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

It's hard to understand what you want to achieve. Why did you remove a column in output.csv?

Also consider reviewing create a minimal, reproducible example then come back and update the question; addressing minimal - provide just enough lines to show the requirements - 2-3 files is sufficient, 3-5 (unique) lines for each file would also be sufficient (we don't need to see 56 lines of 0's nor 24 lines of 360000,135000,180000,22500); addressing complete - provide a textual description for all requirements (eg, why do you ignore the 4th column? what do we do if the files do not have the same number of lines?)

run your script through shellcheck.net to see what's causing your issue, the fix is trivial.
